# pyinstaller FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

**This Is Error Which I Got in Cmd** i Used *pyrogram* which is telegram client library

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyroses.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pyrogram\client\client.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pyrogram\client\methods\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pyrogram\client\methods\bots\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pyrogram\client\ext\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pyrogram\client\ext\base_client.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pyrogram\client\ext\base_client.py", line 80, in BaseClient
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\DarkWeb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI113122\\pyrogram\\client\\ext/mime.types'
[14764] Failed to execute script pyroses
```

just i used pyrogram library and used client.get_me()
my code

```py
import pyrogram
client = pyrogram.Client(
            session_name,
            api_id=****,
            api_hash="****"
        ).start()
print(client.get())
```

i converted it into exe using pyinstaller -F -i icon.ico pyroses.py and it showed me this

Comment: Does this file exist 'C:\\Users\\DarkWeb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI113122\\pyrogram\\client\\ext/mime.types' ?

Comment: It's executable it should be runned everywhere, while compiling it didn't showed me any error, so I have share this I have to share that mime.types too?

Comment: If the program needs to access this file, it should be able to find it. I understand that the cause of the errors is that the program cannot find this file. As shown in the line:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\DarkWeb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI113122\\pyrogram\\client\\ext/mime.types'
[14764]
The solution depends on the type of file and its usage by the program. You could ship the file together with the program, or have the program create it.
This looks like a runtime error, it may not be detectable during compilation.